# Display the records in main report from sub-report

Tags: crystal-reports

i need to display the records of subreports which is generated from  the table in horizontal instead of vertical.

Comment: You will need to explain a little more than that.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is 'I need to display my subreport in a left-to-right-top-to-bottom manner, similar to a calendar, how do I do this?', then:

1. add a group to the main report
2. set the Details section to 'Format
   with Multiple Columns' (found in the
   Section Expert)
3. use the Layout tab to modify
   properties accordingly.

This explanation assumes that your subreport is narrow enough to do so.

If this isn't your question, please clarify it.  A *lot* more.